# Index-pack abnormal exit during git push

Tags: git

I am continuously getting error after rebase master branch at my feature branch. I have searched google and find some solutions but nothing worked for me. After rebase I execute **git status**. it returns like this

```
On branch test/263-junit-test-390
Your branch and 'origin/test/263-junit-test-390' have diverged,
and have 60 and 35 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

After that I run **git push -f origin branch_name**. I am getting this.

```
Counting objects: 568, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (271/271), done.
Writing objects: 100% (568/568), 9.32 MiB | 703.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 568 (delta 304), reused 454 (delta 202)
error: index-pack died of signal 98/304)
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+died+of+signal+9

Comment: SO it requires server configuration change?

Comment: Well, that, or push something that doesn't overload the server. But usually it's better to fix the problem where it's occurring, i.e., server-side.

Comment: But I have no control over git server. And how can I detect which file is overloading ????

Comment: Those are both difficult problems, yes. In general, it's large files that cause problems. I see roughly 10 MB sent, with just 568 objects; perhaps there's one extra-large one? 10 MB itself is not very big though, so it seems more likely to be a server misconfiguration problem.

Comment: At last successful. I have close some process of my local machine that was taking too much memory. Then push is now success.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have noticed that this is not a `remote: error: ...` so it occurred on your machine, not on the server.

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happen when we committed large file anytime. Suppose after committed,  we delete this file but if it once pushed in past it will make problem. 
Although these large files deleted it will repack again when we push our local changes on git and then it takes long time.

We can check our commit history by using this command

```
git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | sed -n 's/^blob //p' | sort --numeric-sort --key=2 | cut -c 1-12,41- | $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest
```

Then we have to clear these file history from git. and then it will work. To clear history we can follow this link

https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

**NB** : I added this answer because may it helps to others